# Google Plus error when trying to display accounts: AccountSignUpActivity: Resolution intents must be called with startIntentSenderForResult

Tags: android, google-plus

I'm using play-services:4.0.30 SDK in my app currently, and when trying to login with Google+, sometimes the SDK does not respond when trying to display the AccountSignUpActivity (Choose an account dialog). I'm not clear why I get this intermittent error or how to resolve it.

I've set-up the plus-client initialization pretty much straight forward as the [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started#step_3_initialize_the_plusclient) suggests.

However, on occasion I get the following error w/out any exception or error result:

```
AccountSignUpActivity: Resolution intents must be called with startIntentSenderForResult
```

This error is always preceded by the expected case when the user is not authenticated:

```
connection failed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED, resolution=PendingIntent{433ee4e8: android.os.BinderProxy@426fbc28}}
```

Here's my code that handles the normal connection failure:

```
   @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        L.e("connection failed: " + connectionResult);
        if (mIsLoggingIn) {
            // The user clicked the sign-in button already. Start to resolve
            // connection errors. Wait until onConnected() to dismiss the
            // connection dialog.
            if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
                try {
                    connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(activity, REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR);
                } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                    mPlusClient.connect();
                }
            }

        // Save the intent so that we can start an activity when the user clicks
        // the sign-in button.
        mConnectionResult = connectionResult;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the no other place that might be using the connection result? I see that you do store it, so I am wondering if there might be other code around that (particularly are you doing anything in the onActivityResult?).

Other thing to try is updating to the latest Google Play services, 4.1

Comment: I updated to the Google Play services 4.1 and I get a new warning telling me the I needed to start the activity with a proper activity context. The issue was that I had a singleton login session manager that tracked my (one an only) app activity, which became stale when 'onDestory' was called. So I just had to make sure to take down the instance and ensure the activity context was still valid when trying to initiate the account resolution. I never did get any response in onActivityResult! Thanks for the tip!